# How does OverloadedStrings language extension work?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand the language extension OverloadedStrings from the page  https://ocharles.org.uk/posts/2014-12-17-overloaded-strings.html.

When the OverloadedStrings is enabled, then `String` becomes a type `Data.String.IsString a => a`:

```
Prelude Data.String> :t fromString "Foo"
fromString "Foo" :: IsString a => a
```

In the description, the author has mentioned the following:

> By enabling this extension, string literals are now a call to the
>   fromString function, which belongs to the IsString type class.

What does `string literals are now a call to the fromString function` ?

and also the author has mentioned:

> This polymorphism is extremely powerful, and it allows us to write
>   embedded domain specific languages in Haskell source code, without
>   having to introduce new constructs for otherwise normal values.

what does `without having to introduce new constructs for otherwise normal values` mean?

Comment: I'm not sure I can satisfactorily answer your specific questions - but the way I think of it is making string literals polymorphic, just as number literals are. The literal value `2` doesn't have type `Integer`, it has type `Num a => a` - so can serve duty as an `Int`, `Integer`, `Double` or whatever. Similarly, with `OverloadedStrings`, the literal `"hello"` is no longer simply a `String` (which remember means `[Char]`), it's `IsString a => a`, so can also be `Text` or `ByteString` or whatever other type you want it to be.

Comment: OverloadedStrings does not affect or change `String`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When the OverloadedStrings is enabled, then `String` becomes a type `Data.String.IsString a => a`

No that is incorrect. A `String` remains a `String`. It has only effect on string *literals*, not variables that have as type a `String`, and these still *can* be `String`s.

> What does *string literals are now a call to the `fromString` function*?

It means that if you write a *string literal*, like `"foo"`, Haskell implicitly writes `fromString "foo"`, and thus you can use this like any `IsString` object.

> what does *without having to introduce new constructs for otherwise normal values* mean?

It means that we can make our own types for which we can write some sort of "mini-parser", and thus write these objects as string literals in our code. For example if we make a datatype like:

```
newtype BoolList = BoolList [Bool] deriving Show
```

then we can write our own parser

```
instance IsString BoolList where
    fromString = BoolList . map toBool
        where toBool '1' = True
              toBool _ = False
```

Now we can for example define a list of `Bool`s as:

```
myboollist :: BoolList
myboollist = "10110010001"
```

So then we get:

```
Prelude Data.String> myboollist 
BoolList [True,False,True,True,False,False,True,False,False,False,True]
```

We here thus wrote a string literal `"10110010001"`, and that means that implictly, we wrote `fromString "10110010001"`. Since the type of `myboollist` is `BoolList`, it is here clear to what the string literal is parsed.

This thus can be useful if some data types are complex, our would take a lot of code to construct an object.

Since the `fromString` call is however postponed, and frequently not *all* possible strings map to a value of the type (here it is the case, although it is debatable if it is good to just fill in `False` for everything else than `'1'`), it thus can raise errors at runtime when the string turns out to be "unparsable".

Comment: *"Haskell implicitly writes `fromString "foo"`"* that's circular.

Comment: @WillNess: no, since the condition is that "if *you* write `"foo"`", so if Haskell writes `fromString "foo"`, then that does not trigger a new rule :)

Comment: A code is a code, no matter who wrote it. I read that as *"the code `"foo"` stands for `fromString "foo"`"* and it is still circular. `fromString ("foo" :: String)` is OTOH clear (for me, at least). :)

Comment: 1) `fromString :: IsString a => String -> String`, so `fromString "foo"` is already "not circular" by your standards 2) `fromString ("foo" :: String)` is actually still "circular", because that would mean `fromString (fromString "foo" :: String)`, ad infinitum. I think the correct answer is that “Haskell" and "Haskell + `OverloadedStrings`" are different languages, and the rule transates from the latter to the former. It’s not circular because the target langauge is different. In GHC, the most basic functional language is Core, which is even lower than standard Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

> what does without having to introduce new constructs for otherwise normal values mean?

The next sentence says

> > So why should string literals be any different?

so this one refers primarily to number literals. Consider e.g. [a type defining polynomials](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/polynomial-0.7.3/docs/Math-Polynomial.html). Because `+` and `*` can only be applied to arguments of the same type, if we want

```
2*x^3 + 3*x :: Poly Int
```

to be legal, `2` and `3` have to be of type `Poly Int`; otherwise you'd need either

1. a separate operator to multiply a polynomial by a number: `2.*x^3 + 3.^x`.
2. a constructor for a constant polynomial: `(C 2)*x^3 + (C 3)*x`

An example for string literals is given at the end:

> > However, SQL queries are notorious for injection attacks when we concatenate strings. Interestingly, postgresql-simple provides a `Query` type that only has a `IsString` instance. This means that it’s very lightweight to write a literal query, but the moment we want to start concatenating strings for our query, we have to be very explicit.